# Git last commit hash and current version

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In my Elixir/Phoenix application I want to show the current commit hash from git and version number from the mix.exs file on an html page. How can I do that? That is, is there access to this kind of information at all?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci, nothing

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci, nothing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To extract the current commit hash, I have this solution:

```
{hash, _} = System.cmd("git", ["rev-parse", "HEAD"])
# => {"5f6910ce1f42d5026d0ec5544ce6df9c3f8caf17\n", 0}

String.trim(hash)
# => "5f6910ce1f42d5026d0ec5544ce6df9c3f8caf17"
```

To get the app version you can try this:

```
{:ok, vsn} = :application.get_key(:my_app, :vsn)
# => {:ok, '0.1.1'}

vsn
# => '0.1.1'

List.to_string(vsn)
# => "0.1.1"
```

Replace the atom :my_app with your app atom.

Or you use:

```
Mix.Project.config[:version]
# => "0.1.1"
```

See [Mix.Project.config](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Project.html#config/0) for more information.

Comment: `** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Mix.Project.config/0 is undefined (module Mix.Project is not available)`

Comment: and also it says in the doc-ion "Do not use Mix.Project.config/0 to find the runtime configuration. Use it only to configure aspects of your project (like compilation directories) and not your application runtime."

Comment: Ok, I see. I don't understand, why the docs say, we should not use it. `MyApp.Mixfile.project()[:version]` should do it too.

Answer (score 0):

I display it in a phoenix app like this:

View

```
@version Mix.Project.config()[:version]
@hash System.cmd("git", ["rev-parse", "--short", "HEAD"]) |> elem(0) |> String.trim()
def version(), do: @version
def hash(), do: @hash
```

Template

```
<%= hash() %>
```

The advantage being that this is a compile time variable and fixed during the release.